# Octopress errors - rake preview, watch or generate

Tags: ruby, rake, jekyll, rakefile, octopress

I followed all instructions in [Octopress Documentation](http://octopress.org/docs/):

```
sddhrthrt@thinkpad:~/octopress$ rake generate
## Generating Site with Jekyll
directory source/stylesheets/ 
   create source/stylesheets/screen.css 
Configuration from /home/sddhrthrt/octopress/_config.yml
/home/sddhrthrt/octopress/plugins/pygments_code.rb:5: 
      warning: already initialized constant PYGMENTS_CACHE_DIR
/home/sddhrthrt/octopress/plugins/render_partial.rb:25:in `require':
             ./plugins/octopress_filters.rb:69: undefined (?...) sequence:
              /<div class="entry-content">(?<content>[\s\S]*?)<\/div>\s*<(footer|\/article)>/ (SyntaxError)
        from /home/sddhrthrt/octopress/plugins/render_partial.rb:25
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:76:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:76:in `setup'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:75:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:75:in `setup'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:30:in `initialize'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/jekyll:224:in `new'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/jekyll:224
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:19
```

And

```
sddhrthrt@thinkpad:~/octopress$ rake preview
Starting to watch source with Jekyll and Compass. Starting Rack on port 4000
rake aborted!
undefined method `spawn' for Process:Module

Tasks: TOP => preview
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

and

```
sddhrthrt@thinkpad:~/octopress$ rake watch
Starting to watch source with Jekyll and Compass.
rake aborted!
undefined method `spawn' for Process:Module

Tasks: TOP => watch
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've never worked on Ruby, I admit. Hence i'm not very comfortable unscrambling the errors. Google search also didn't yield anything I could comprehend.

**EDIT:**

So mentioned in the answers, I installed rbenv and then `ruby 1.9.3-p327`. I came back to `~/octopress` and ran `bundle install` and it said all the gems were already installed (I had done that when I had ruby 1.8x). And now rake gives me this error:

```
sddhrthrt@thinkpad:~/octopress$ rake --trace
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/sddhrthrt/octopress/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/sddhrthrt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
```

Should I reinstall using bundle all the gems? I cant understand.

Comment: What Ruby version do you have? (EDIT: I've noticed that you have 1.8.X)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
```

in your site's root folder. Note, `1.9.3` is your Ruby version.

Then I think when you run

```
$ rake watch
```

or

```
$ rake preview
```

will work now.

---

#### EDIT:

So, for `rbenv`, try:

```
$ rbenv global 1.9.3-p327
```

or you can use `local` instead.

Comment: i'm not using rvm. I used rbenv to install the new ruby

Comment: @SiddharthaRT you can try `rbenv global 1.9.3-p327`.

Comment: I tried that already. The problem is, when i do `build exec rake`, it uses binaries from `Ruby 1.8`.

Comment: @SiddharthaRT `ruby -v` to check what the really version is in using?

Comment: okay, after a lot of juggling, i guess I've messed up the whole ruby setup in my comp. When i run ruby, I get this error now - `<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the problem is with outdated Ruby. According to this: https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/142 you should be on Ruby 1.9 (the stable version is now 1.9.3-p327). You can get this directly from Ruby site, but I would suggest using RVM (or rbenv) to setup your Ruby environment.

You can find a guide how to install RVM on your box here: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Then installing Ruby 1.9.3 will be as simple as:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
rvm --default 1.9.3
rvm reload
```

Then you will have to install all the dependancies with `bundle install` (to get `bundler`: `gem install bundler`) in Octopress root directory.

**EDIT:**

Also `.rvmrc` in Octopress' project root says that it requires Ruby 1.9.3: https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/.rvmrc

Comment: I've put the changes in the question.

Comment: Have you tried running tasks with `bundle exec`? For example `bundle exec rake preview`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you miss step 3 of rbenv configuration ?

```
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/#rbenv-shell