# Octopress SyntaxError on rake generate

Tags: ruby, octopress

I have managed to start Octopress with a few posts and pages, but I am now getting an `SyntaxError` that I am not able to identify:

```
....# rake generate
(in /var/serv.example.com/public_html/blog)
Generating Site with Jekyll
identical source/stylesheets/screen.css
Configuration from /var/www/ser.exampe.com/public_html/blog/_config.yml
/var/www/serv.example.com/public_html/blog/plugins/render_partial.rb:25:in `require': ./plugins/octopress_filters.rb:69: undefined (?...) sequence: /<div class="entry-content">(?<content>[\s\S]*?)<\/div>\s*<(footer|\/article)>/ (SyntaxError)
```

Comment: What are you passing to the filter? In my deployment, it is only used once--to fetch the page description. It could be some other content is exposing a bug with the regular expression.

Comment: ok.. but how to locate it using this error log, i mean in which file ?

Comment: Look at your codebase in plugins/octopress_filters.rb. Your line 69 and mine are identical. As I said, that filter is only used once in my stuff, and it works. If you are applying it to something else, that could explain something.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a `ruby`/`rake` version error.

See [Octopress errors - rake preview, watch or generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778858/octopress-errors-rake-preview-watch-or-generate)